# Grunt UnCSS doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, uncss

I'm trying to use "uncss" with grunt, i do all the process, i followed [this guide](http://xdamman.com/website-optimization-grunt-uncss) but got no success, the page doesn't show anything, [here are my files](https://github.com/JonathanSolorzano/bancofit-website/tree/uncss), i don't know what happens. Maybe someone with more experience in this can help. Also would like to know if when using many frameworks it's recommended to use this method to mash the js files up and minify them?

How safe is to use uncss? i've run it file by file but it erases things that are used by the page... what are the limitations of uncss?

Comment: any errors after running the command? please add it here. ill glad to help.

Comment: @celerno No, no errors

Comment: @calemo What seems weird for me is that when i run uncss file bi file it erase things it shouldn't couse they're used